# Quick help on showing a set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I am working on a constraint optimization problem. I have found the extrema and all I need to do now is to show that the set S that the critical points are defined in is bounded and closed (therefore compact, thus has its max and min...).

Here is the set:

$S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ g(x,y)=3 \}  \\  g(x,y) = x^2 + xy + y^2 $

I know that I can also use the border Hessian to show the boundedness condition but usually some algebra work on the inequalities enable me to separately contain $x$ and $y$ in some interval.

For instance for

$ g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 $

since $ 0 \le x^2$, $y^2 \leq 3 $ thus $ \\ |y| \le \sqrt{3} \ \ $   i.e. $ -\sqrt{3} \le y \le \sqrt{3} $ and the same for x. Yet with the above function I failed to figure out the bounds... Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

If $(x,y)\in S$ then you have the following bounds:

\begin{equation}
x^2+xy+y^2=3\Rightarrow xy\leq 3,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x^2+xy+y^2 =(x+y)^{2}-xy =3\Rightarrow xy\geq -3.
\end{equation}

Now if $(x,y)\in S$ and $x^2+y^2> 6$ then you must have $xy <-3$, so you must have $S\subset B(0,6)$, where $B(0,6)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}/x^2+y^2\leq6\}$, and this set $S$ is bounded.

Comment: I am confused shouldn't $x^2 + y^2 > 6 $ imply that $xy > -3$ or $-xy < -3 $ and also here regarding your terminology what does $B(0,6) $ represent? thank you !

Comment: ok so from $x^2 + y^2 +xy = 3$ I can claim that since $ 0 \le x^2 + y^2$ it should be that $ xy \le 3$ and from  $(x+y)^{2}-xy =3 \rightarrow -3 \le xy$. Thus we have a bound for $xy$ ! Then using $-3 \le xy$ I can claim that $x^2 + y^2 \le 6$ thus we also bounded $x^2 + y^2$ between $0$ and $6$! And from what I understand bounding $x^2 + y^2$ and $xy$ is another way to show that the equation is bounded?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is correct but based on the previous answer here is mine.

from $x^2 + y^2 +xy = 3$

I can claim that: since $ 0 \le x^2 + y^2$ it should be that $ xy \le 3$

and $(x+y)^{2}-xy =3 \rightarrow -3 \le xy$.

Then using $-3 \le xy$ I can claim that $x^2 + y^2 \le 6$ thus we also bounded $x^2 + y^2$ between $0$ and $6$

So we combine both and we get $-3 \le x^2 + y^2 - xy \le 9 $ is this correct ?

And from what I understand bounding $x^2 + y^2$ and $xy$ is another way to show that the equation is bounded?

Comment: Since you have $x^2+y^2\leq 6$ you have a bound on $x$ and $y$.